# TalkBack. Make CardView accessibility

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I want make my CardView more accessibility. I have clickable CardView and i want talkback voiced this CardView with role "button". I dont know how to do it.

```
private fun setAccessibilityDescription(view: View) {
        ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(view, object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {

            override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View, info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat) {
                super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
                info.className = Button::class.java.name
            }
        })
    }
```

I tryed  use ViewCompat and override onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo, it is helped me but not fully. Role "button" always voiced first, although talkback usually say "button" last with real button. It's better than nothing, but how can I make the TalkBack sound my CardView like a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible! Instead of className, you need a role description. By calling [setRoleDescription](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat#setRoleDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)), you can set this as Button.

For example:

```
info.roleDescription = getString(R.string.button)
```

Comment: I used this method, but the result was the same as with the className. The word "button" sounds first too

Comment: Do you have both, contentDescription and roleDescription, set inside onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo, or is just roleDescription set, and content description comes from the views inside CardView?

Comment: Second version. Do I need to set contentDescription manually with roleDescription?

Comment: I think what might be happening, Talkback is reading the content description of entire CardView first, so only reads "Button", then it follows with contents of CardView, ie whatever child views are in there. If you set both contentDescription and roleDescription on CardView, it should have the behaviour you need.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will try this solution a little bit later

Comment: I really appreciate you, its work. For correct sound, i set contentDescription and roleDescription

Answer (score 0):

I tryed different ways and i think talkback api dont support set custom object like button. For my solution i choiced use contentDescription, i just add word "button" to end of contentDescription my object

```
private fun setAccessibilityViewTypeInfo(view: View, contentDescription: String) {
        ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(view, object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {

            override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View, info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat) {
                super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
                info.contentDescription = host.context.resources.getString(
                    designR.string.talkback_button_pattern,
                    contentDescription
                )
            }
        })
    }
```

In my code contentDescription it is all text into my CardView and talkback_button_pattern

```
<string name="talkback_button_pattern">%1$s, button</string>
```

I understand that people can change talkback behavior in settings.
Depending on the settings, the word "button" can be at the end or at the beginning of the voice acting and my solution don't support this case. But  it's better than nothing